# How to join 2 tables in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have two models a projects and a tasks. On the task model I have a fK project_id, and 2 integer fields to enter duration in mins and hours.
I want to click on the project, get its id and then look into the task table and calculate the hours and mins for that project based on all the tasks that have the fk of the project_id.

Here is what I've tried

Project - Model

```
public static function getTotalHoursInProgressProject() {
    $project =Project::all();
    $projectHrsProgress = Task::where('project_id', '=', 'project.id')->where('board_column_id', '=' ,'6')->sum('duration_hrs');
    $taskHours =  $projectHrsProgress * 60;
    $projectMinProgress = Task::where('project_id', '=', 'project.id')->where('board_column_id', '=' ,'6')->sum('duration_min');
    $finalHrsInprogress = ($taskHours + $projectMinProgress )*0.016667;
    // $finalHrsInprogressTotal = (float) $finalHrsInprogress;

    return number_format((float)$finalHrsInprogress, 2, '.', '');;
  }
```

In the controller

```
public function show($id)

{

    $this->project = Project::findOrFail($id);
    $this->categories = TaskCategory::all();
    $this->taskInProgress = Project::getTotalHoursInProgressProject();


    return view('admin.projects.tasks.show', $this->data);
}
```

In the view

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="white-box p-t-10 p-b-10 bg-warning">
                                                <h3 class="box-title text-white">In Progress Hours</h3>
                                                <ul class="list-inline two-part">
                                                    <li><i class="icon-layers text-white"></i></li>
                                                    <li class="text-right"><span id="" class="counter text-white">{{ $taskInProgress }}</span></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Here is the error I'm getting

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'duration_min' in 'field list' (SQL: select sum(`duration_min`) as aggregate from `tasks` where `project_id` = project.id and `board_column_id` = 6 and `tasks`.`company_id` = 1)

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) .. Also you should provide more PHP code how you defined your models..

Comment: i also wonder if it might be easier and getting more performance to make a view in MySQL ... `CREATE ALGORITHM=MERGE  VIEW ... AS (<query_with_joins>)` and select on that with Laravel..  the `ALGORITHM=MERGE` would optimize/rewrite queries done on the VIEW to the view definition which is better explained in the manual [View Processing Algorithms](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html) ... Which make the VIEW work like a SQL preprocessor or SQL templating engine more easy said...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create laravel has relation in your Project model then you can access the associated data in query.

You can also get the total time by creating two function in model like below.

In Project Model:

```
public function Task()
 {  
   return $this->hasMany('App\Task');    
}

public function TotalTaskHour()
{  
    return $this->hasMany('App\Task')
        ->selectRaw('SUM(duration_hrs) as total_hrs')
        ->groupBy('project_id');    
}

public function TotalTaskMinute()
    {  
        return $this->hasMany('App\Task')
            ->selectRaw('SUM(duration_min) as total_mins')
            ->groupBy('project_id');    
    }
```

Now in your controller access associated data like this.

In controller :

```
public function show($id)
{

    $project = Project::with('TotalTaskHour')->with('TotalTaskMinute')->with('Task')->findOrFail($id);
    $totalHour = $project->TotalTaskHour->total_hrs;
    $totalHoour = $project->TotalTaskHour->total_mins;

   $taskInProgress = $project->getTotalHoursInProgressProject();

    dd($project); 
}
```

Make sure you have also created task model.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks! I was looking for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use one to one relationship between two models Project & Task

```
public function show($id)
{

    $project = Project::with('tasks')->findOrFail($id);
    $taskInProgress = $project->getTotalHoursInProgressProject();


    return view('admin.projects.tasks.show',compact('taskInProgress'));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, however is still not working I'm getting the following error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'duration_min' in 'field list' (SQL: select sum(`duration_min`) as aggregate from `tasks` where `project_id` = project.id and `board_column_id` = 6 and `tasks`.`company_id` = 1)